# Is the term 'put on his parts' used everywhere, or only in some dialects?

Tags: idioms, dialects

In Norfolk, when a child misbehaves in a demanding, or sulking way, they are often said to 'put on their parts'.

'She is *putting on her parts* again', means that she is following a pattern, typical for her, where she is being loud, difficult, insistent or awkward.

It can also be used for adults and has an added force since it suggests they are behaving like a child. But I am wondering if the expression is widely understood?

Presumably it derives from the following meaning of the noun 'parts':

Meaning 12 of on-line OED

> †a. A character sustained, assumed, or feigned by a person, esp. for a special purpose. Also in extended use. Obs.
>
> earlier references deleted.
>
> a1732 J. Gay Fables (1738) II. vi. 47 The man of pure and simple heart Through life disdains a double part. 1885 Dict. National Biogr. at Thomas Blood, It is not improbable that he was at this time..acting a double part, keeping the government informed of so much as might secure his own safety.

Comment: I've never heard it in America (NE,MW,SW,SoCal)

Comment: Nor have I (SE,UMW,LMW). But it's marvellous. [***OED 1***](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/498/mode/2up) doesn't know about it; I wonder whether it derives from sense 9, 11 or 12, or something else entirely.

Comment: Try posting your question to the etymologist Michael Quinion at WorldWideWords.org. He's excellent at winkling out pretty obscure terms, whether dialect or archaic. However, you'll have to take a chance on whether he is able to get to it.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, it would appear to follow the idea of a 'part' played in the theatre. It suggests the child (or adult) is putting on a performance of some kind (which often they are!). I have added  meaning 12 of the OED on-line edition to my OP as this seems to catch the sense. But interestingly the OED does not list 'putting on parts' as a derivative, which makes me wonder if it is even known throughout the UK, or if it is unique to East Anglia. Someone please say! Where are you Fumble Fingers when we need you?

Comment: @StoneyB It may also be connected with the word 'pert', meaning 'saucy', or outspoken. I discovered from the OED when looking that it gives rise to the word 'impertinent'. Seems related.

Comment: @WS2: I wouldn't like to swear I've *never* heard this usage before, but Google Books doesn't have a single written instance of any permutation of *put/putting on his/her parts*. Having said that, in any context I can imagine, the intended sense would probably be obvious, so I wouldn't be particularly likely to *remember* it (I'd naturally assume I could work it out again from context if necessary). To cut a long story short - *No, it's not used everywhere*. In fact, the only online reference I could find apart from this post was in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norfolk_dialect).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I suspected that might be the case. It's an everyday expression in Norfolk. As a child I was frequently accused of it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just looked at the Wiki entry on 'Norfolk Dialect'. Yes it's there all right. The interesting thing is that I wrote most of that entry on 'Grammar', but not the expressions.

Comment: I read that has *She is putting on her **pants***! :)

Comment: Not something I've ever heard in the US, but that's purely anecdotal and negative evidence.

Comment: @tchrist: I never thought of that one, but I can't deny it did cross my mind to deliberately adopt a mischievous interpretation myself - *She is putting on [= displaying] her **private** parts*. Given that [N4N - Normal for Norfolk](http://www.literarynorfolk.co.uk/normal_for_norfolk.htm) can have various implications (some of them sexually loaded), it could feasibly be a colourful local way of saying [*"using her sexual charms"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22using+her+sexual+charms%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers As someone who grew up in Norfolk in the late forties, early fifties (before sex was invented) I can tell you that it has nothing whatever to do with that subject. It is all about a child having a tantrum. I'll leave you to guess which contributor to this site made me think of it. But thanks for the link to N4N. I had not heard of that one.

Comment: I note that the phantom down-voter has been out and about again!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Re N4N, I suppose you know that the village of Happisburgh is pronounced 'Haisbro'.

Comment: @WS2: My ex-wife was a nurse. N4N seems to be primarily associated with hospitals - I'd be astonished if anyone dared to write it on a patient's medical records today, but some health workers certainly use it casually in conversation. Personally, I think it's *funny*, but if anyone took offence I'd immediately be abjectly apologetic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd not heard it before, but I do not actually live in Norfolk. Having said that my father just died (aged 99 years and 291 days) in the Norfolk & Norwich and for about a week I spent my life there but never heard N4N used. There was certainly a lot of N4N about him.

Comment: I've lived in Norfolk most of my life and it was a very common phrase for someone to say He's been putting on his parts all day, meaning he'd been playing up like a child, but I have no idea where this comes from, just that it's been common usage until quite recently.

Answer (score 2):

Per comments to the question, I personally am not familiar with this (apparently, highly localised) dialectal usage. But my guess is *parts* here is being used in much the same way as ...

> [a man of (many) parts](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/a-man-of-many-parts) *- a man with great ability in many different areas*

Picking up on the *theatrical* allusions of "parts", one could also see it as another way of saying...

> *"She's **going through her repertoire** [of irritating behaviour patterns, etc.]"*

---

Given the low prevalence of an expression which seems to be almost exclusively *spoken, colloquial*, I think it's unlikely anyone will be able to turn up a "first use" from which one might be able to determine *precisely* what was in the minds of the people who originally used the term.

Comment: The leading academic authority on the Norfolk Dialect is Professor Peter Trudgill of UEA, a Norwich boy, but with wide interests in local dialects across Europe. He is also president of FOND (Friends of the Norfolk Dialect) of which I am a member. (Barrie England knows all about him). He is also a Professor at the University of Zurich. When I am back home I will check if there is a reference in his book to 'putting on parts'.

Comment: I suppose I could send in a suggestion to the OED. They were very helpful and responsive over another query I once made. I will see what Trudgill says first.

Answer (score 1):

This expression was commonly used during my childhood near Swaffham by parents who were both of Norfolk heritage.